# sharing topics on Facebook

Tags: php, html, facebook

I have a page with facebook share button, how do I specify the image that will be displayed when sharing.

I tried to put an image in meta tag this way:

```
<meta property='og:image' content='image_url' />
```

but it shows no image on facebook still

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: og:tags are the way to specify the content you want to be shared by Facebook. If it's not working, use the link to the debug tool that CBroe provided and make sure the image_url is correct and accessible.

Comment: I found the problem in the url, it should be the complete url notjust the file location,
content='mysite.com/file_location'
and I was using
content='file_cocation'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content must have the full URL of the image not just the file location on the server:
the right way is: content='mysite.com/file_location'
and Not: content='file_cocation'